# Conditionally Count MYSQL Column Rows (Multiple Databases) and Output Data via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, union

I am trying to run a query and get the result from multiple databases (using the UNION clause) on the same server but its not working for me. Table names and column names are the same across all the databases (same cup, same coffee, different "shops" :D). Here is my sql statement:

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT MONTH(ScanDate) AS sdmonth, YEAR(ScanDate) AS sdyear,  
              COUNT(Investigation) AS Investigation, COUNT(CASE WHEN `Gender` = 'Male' THEN 1 END) AS MaleCount, 
              COUNT(CASE WHEN `Gender` = 'Female' THEN 1 END) AS FemaleCount, SUM(InvestigationAmount) AS investigationAmount, SUM(AmountDue) AS AmountDue   
                    FROM `database1`.`table_name`
                    UNION
                    SELECT MONTH(ScanDate) AS sdmonth, YEAR(ScanDate) AS sdyear,  
              COUNT(Investigation) AS Investigation, COUNT(CASE WHEN `Gender` = 'Male' THEN 1 END) AS MaleCount, 
              COUNT(CASE WHEN `Gender` = 'Female' THEN 1 END) AS FemaleCount, SUM(InvestigationAmount) AS investigationAmount, SUM(AmountDue) AS AmountDue   
                    FROM `database2`.`table_name` 
                    WHERE (ScanDate BETWEEN '{$ScanDate1}' AND '{$ScanDate2}')
UNION
SELECT MONTH(ScanDate) AS sdmonth, YEAR(ScanDate) AS sdyear,  
              COUNT(Investigation) AS Investigation, COUNT(CASE WHEN `Gender` = 'Male' THEN 1 END) AS MaleCount, 
              COUNT(CASE WHEN `Gender` = 'Female' THEN 1 END) AS FemaleCount, SUM(InvestigationAmount) AS investigationAmount, SUM(AmountDue) AS AmountDue   
                    FROM `database3`.`table_name` 
                    WHERE (ScanDate BETWEEN '{$ScanDate1}' AND '{$ScanDate2}')");


    //-create  while loop and loop through result set
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $month_doe=$row['sdmonth']; 
    $year_doe=$row['sdyear'];
    $si=$row['Investigation'];
    $male=$row['MaleCount'];
    $female=$row['FemaleCount'];
    $sum_investigation=number_format($si);
    $sia=$row['investigationAmount'];
    $sum_investigationamount=number_format($sia);
    $srd=$row['AmountDue'];
    $sum_rebatedue=number_format($srd);
    }
```

I AM DEFINITELY IN OVER MY HEAD and doing a lotta things wrong, as this only outputs result for the second database. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

On the off-chance that i also have a problem in my connection parameters, Here are my connection details:

```
<?php  
    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
     if (!$conn)
    {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("", $conn);
?>
```

Comment: What is the error that you can see for both the query execution and while connecting to the database ?

Comment: @Webdev I do not see any errors. It simply gives me a result for `database2`.`table_name`. (In this case i am trying the query for only 2 databases.

Comment: Print the query and run it on the database using phpmyadmin or whatever tool you are using...if still it only returns result from database1, then chances are that there are no records in database2 and database3

Comment: Running it on the database via phpmyadmin gives me a result for database1.table_name.

Comment: Can you check if there are records in  database2 and database3 for the table names used

Comment: Yes there are records for database2 (database3 was used for illustration). running the select queries independently for each database gives me results. COUNT(Investigation) for databse1.table_name = 24,251 records, also COUNT(Investigation) for databse2.table_name = 1,578 records. But what i want to do is to run the single query and get all sum across all the databases. In this case, 25,829 records. Thanks for your help so far mate.

Comment: Isn't this the same SQL (besides the database name) repeated three times? Not familiar with PHP, but perhaps some form of string interpolation would make this easier to read?

Comment: Yes it is. I do not understand what "string interpolation" means though.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things are worth looking at. Firstly, by default, UNION in MySQL runs as DISTINCT, discarding rows that it considers to be equal.

If you're wanting to return all rows, you'd need to use UNION ALL instead of just UNION.

I would try it with UNION ALL.

If that still doesn't work, you're providing aliases for all of your variables in a way that might be playing havoc with how they're returned.

I would amend that to remove the aliases for the second and third select statements, like so:

```
"SELECT MONTH(ScanDate) AS sdmonth, YEAR(ScanDate) AS sdyear,  
          COUNT(Investigation) AS Investigation, COUNT(CASE WHEN `Gender` = 'Male' THEN 1 END) AS MaleCount, 
          COUNT(CASE WHEN `Gender` = 'Female' THEN 1 END) AS FemaleCount, SUM(InvestigationAmount) AS investigationAmount, SUM(AmountDue) AS AmountDue   
                FROM `database1`.`table_name`
                UNION ALL
                SELECT MONTH(ScanDate), YEAR(ScanDate),  
          COUNT(Investigation), COUNT(CASE WHEN `Gender` = 'Male' THEN 1 END), 
          COUNT(CASE WHEN `Gender` = 'Female' THEN 1 END), SUM(InvestigationAmount), SUM(AmountDue)   
                FROM `database2`.`table_name` 
                WHERE (ScanDate BETWEEN '{$ScanDate1}' AND '{$ScanDate2}')
UNION ALL
SELECT MONTH(ScanDate), YEAR(ScanDate),  
          COUNT(Investigation), COUNT(CASE WHEN `Gender` = 'Male' THEN 1 END), 
          COUNT(CASE WHEN `Gender` = 'Female' THEN 1 END), SUM(InvestigationAmount), SUM(AmountDue)
                FROM `database3`.`table_name` 
                WHERE (ScanDate BETWEEN '{$ScanDate1}' AND '{$ScanDate2}')"
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your input. I tried it your way (with 2 databases, database1.table_name and database2.table_name) but results still the same. It only outputs results for the second database, not all. To verify this, i switched the databases around.......database2.table_name in the first part then database1.table_name in the second part after UNION ALL. The bottomline is, this query only outputs data for the last select statement, which is not what a UNION should do.

Comment: It finally works. Couldn't see the solution starring me in the face all along. Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 0):

It works finally. Simple answers are difficult to see at times. SQL statement I needed to do all along was this:

```
SELECT COUNT(Investigation) AS Investigation, COUNT(CASE WHEN `Gender` = 'Male' THEN 1 END) 
                        AS MaleCount, COUNT(CASE WHEN `Gender` = 'Female' THEN 1 END) AS FemaleCount, 
                        SUM(InvestigationAmount) AS investigationAmount, SUM(AmountDue) AS AmountDue   
                        FROM 
                        (SELECT * FROM `database1`.`table_name` WHERE ScanDate BETWEEN '{$ScanDate1}' 
                        AND '{$ScanDate2}'
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT * FROM `database2`.`table_name` WHERE ScanDate BETWEEN '{$ScanDate1}' 
                        AND '{$ScanDate2}') table_alias_here
```

Thanks for your input guys. Totally appreciated.